# Orientation Preserving maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a little stumped on the following question.  Not sure how to begin.

If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then is $f$ defined by $f(x) = -x$ orientation preserving?

Comment: How are you defining an orientation of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Not exactly sure.  I know what orientable is, just not really what orientation preserving is.

Comment: Does a reflection preserve orientation?

Answer (score 1):

The orientation is preserved if the determinant of the transformation's associated matrix is $+1$. What is the determinant of the matrix associated with $x\mapsto -x$?

Comment: So it would be no if n is odd, and yes if n is even?

Comment: That's how it seems to me.